# Get everything after word

Tags: php, regex

Take this Lorem Ipsum text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla felis diam, mattis id elementum eget, ullamcorper et purus.

How can I with PHP and regex get everything that comes after `Nulla`?

Comment: You want the words from the second sentence onwards? Or do you want the text after "Nulla" specifically?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Hmm you don't want to use some simple things like :

```
$str = substr($lorem, strpos($lorem, 'Nulla'));
```

if you do not want to look for Nulla, but also for 'null' you might consider using stripos instead of strpos...
This code will include Nulla in the returned value. If you want to exclude Nulla, you might want to add it's lentgh to the strpos value i.e

```
$str = substr($lorem, strpos($lorem, 'Nulla') + 5);
```

At last, if you need to have something a bit more generic, and as suggested @Francis :

```
$needle = 'Nulla'; 
$str = substr($lorem, strpos($lorem, $needle) + strlen($needle));
```

Honestly regexp are overkill for something like this...

Comment: If you want to limit the resulting string, use the third argument of substr: `$str = substr($lorem, strpos($lorem, 'Nulla'), 50);` will return 50 characters starting with 'Nulla'

Comment: for the second example I'd take it just a bit further: `$sample = 'Nulla'; $str = substr($lorem, strpos($lorem, $sample) + strlen($sample));` instead of a magic `5` use `strlen`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla felis diam, mattis id elementum eget, ullamcorper et purus.";
$prefix = "Nulla";
$index = strpos($string, $prefix) + strlen($prefix);
$result = substr($string, $index);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/Nulla(.*)/
```

Now you have all the text after Nulla in $1

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla felis diam, mattis id elementum eget, ullamcorper et purus.';

preg_match('/Nulla(.*)/',$string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best option but you can consider following where suits:

```
<?php

$myString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla felis diam, mattis id elementum eget, ullamcorper et purus.";
$explodedArray = explode("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla",$myString);
echo $explodedArray[1];
```