# Extract a part of the string

Tags: php

I have the path as follows in my variable.

```
$str='./application/language/english\admin\settings_lang.php';
```

How can I extract the part of the string after english\? I need to get admin\settings_lang.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: use substr or regular expressions :) READ the PHP manual about how to use them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get everything after word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290279/get-everything-after-word)

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode function

```
$str= './application/language/english\admin\settings_lang.php';
$result = explode('english',$str);
echo $result[1];
```

Comment: Might be better to make this dynamic by changing the last line to `echo end($result);`

Answer (score 0):

Use substr [php substr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$str='./application/language/english\admin\settings_lang.php';
$newStr= substr($str, strpos($str, '\\') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is fixed you can just use the PHP function [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and count how many places you need. Example:

```
$str='./application/language/english\admin\settings_lang.php';
$newStr = substr($str, -23);
```

If it's not of fixed length, but you know "admin" or some other substring will always be in there, you can combine substr with strpos like this:

```
$str='./application/language/other_stuff/dynamic/who_knows/english\admin\settings_lang.php';
$newStr = substr($str, strpos($str, 'admin'));
```

You can see strpos [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Answer (score -2):

Hi try the following code,

**UPDATE**

```
$str='./application/language/english\admin\settings_lang.php';    
$whatIWant = substr($str, strpos($str, "\\") + 1);    
echo $whatIWant;
```

Now check

Comment: This will trigger a parse error thanks to `"\"`. Please test code before posting as an answer.