# Get the string after a certain word from array elements

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a txt file that I have read it as an array (each line in the txt file as an array element). I am interested only with the array elements that started with word "Keywords:". I do need to extract all the words after the word "Keywords:" and save them in another array. To search all the txt file I used loop using foreach. But I do NOT know how to get the string after the "Keywords:".

Example of the txt file:

xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
Keywords: Weathering; Photo-oxidation; Stabilization; Polypropylene; Antarctica; HALS
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Keywords: Antarctica; Disdrometer; Snowfall rate; Radar; Uncertainty quantification

I would like to have the final array contains only "Weathering; Photo-oxidation; Stabilization; Polypropylene; Antarctica; HALS; Antarctica; Disdrometer; Snowfall rate; Radar; Uncertainty quantification

the code that I use:

```
<?php
        // Get a file into an array.   
        // the file saved at C:\Tamer\Open Polar\New Keywords\Original citations files\combined.txt

$lines = file('C:\Tamer\Open Polar\New Keywords\Original citations files\combined.txt');

        // Loop through our array, show HTML source as HTML source.

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {

            $key = strstr($line, ' ', true);
            if ($key = "Keywords:"){
// I do not know how to get the string after the "Keyword:"
            echo "$key" . "<br />\n";

            }


}
?>
```

Anyone can help??

Comment: We know the string you want begins after "Keywords: ", but you don't tell us where that string stops. At the end of the line?

Comment: yes - line start with "Keywords:" followed by string (that I need) and ended by the end of the line. Note each line is saved as array element

Answer (score 0):

This example keeps it simple, really only adding using the `explode()` function

```
$lines = "
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx Keywords: Weathering; Photo-oxidation; Stabilization; Polypropylene; Antarctica; HALS
xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx Keywords: Antarctica; Disdrometer; Snowfall rate; Radar; Uncertainty quantification
This line does not have any
xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx Keywords: some more; keywords";
$linesArr = explode("\n",$lines);
$keywords = array();
foreach ($linesArr as $line_num => $line) {
  $lineArr = explode("Keywords:",$line);
  if (array_key_exists(1,$lineArr)){
    $lineKeywords = explode('; ',$lineArr[1]);
    foreach ($lineKeywords as $keyword){
      $keywords[] = $keyword;
    }   
  }
}
var_dump($keywords);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you just need to get **string** after "Keyword" you can take solution from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11290329/1555546).

So in your case it may look like this:

```
$needle = 'Keyword:'; 

// string after needle
$result = substr($line, strpos($line, $needle) + strlen($needle));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string starts with `Keywords:` and you want to add what follows to an array, one option is to use for example [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
$lines = file('C:\Tamer\Open Polar\New Keywords\Original citations files\combined.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$finalArray = [];
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    if (substr( $line, 0, 9 ) === "Keywords:") {
        $finalArray[] = substr($line, 10);
    }
}

var_export($finalArray);
```

Output

```
array (
  0 => 'Weathering; Photo-oxidation; Stabilization; Polypropylene; Antarctica; HALS',
  1 => 'Antarctica; Disdrometer; Snowfall rate; Radar; Uncertainty quantification',
)
```